# In JavaScript, why non-existent "window" property values differ in these two situations?

Tags: javascript, properties, global

I have a piece of JavaScript code:

```
var o = {
    name: "aaaa",
    f: function () {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.name);
    }
};

var m1 = o.f;
m1();

console.log(window.non_existent_property);
```

As I understand, the property name shouldn't matter too much. If I change the name of property `name` of object `o` to something like `a` everywhere, I should have the same result. However, this is not the case. See below image. I'm running the code on FireFox 75.0. Could anyone explain what is happening here please?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with the property of `o` in the *object* - the property name there is actually *completely irrelevant*, because you're losing the calling context when you assign the function to a standalone variable:

```
var m1 = o.f;
m1();
```

The above code means that `m1` is called with no calling context, which means that `this` inside the `m1` function will either be the global object (in sloppy mode), or `undefined` (in strict mode).

Since you're in sloppy mode, `this.name` references `window.name`, which is a [*reserved property*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) that always exists on `window` and must always be a string. It defaults to the empty string.

Here's another snippet demonstrating the same sort of issue:

```js
var foo = 'foo';
var o = {
    f: function () {
        console.log(this.foo);
    }
};

var m1 = o.f;
m1();
```

`foo` is a property of the window, since a global variable named `foo` was declared with `var`, so `this.foo` references `window.foo`.

Comment: Oh d'oh! I don't know `name` IS a property of `window`. Thanks for the answer!